# Extract the mean from svy mean result in Stata

Tags: stata, survey

I am able to extract the mean into a matrix as follows:

```
svy: mean age, over(villageid)
matrix villagemean = e(b)'
clear
svmat village
```

However, I also want to merge this mean back to the `villageid`. My current thinking is to extract the rownames of the matrix `villagemean` like so:

```
local names : rownames villagemean
```

Then try to turn this macro `names` into variable

```
foreach v in names {
    gen `v' = "``v''"
}
```

However, the variable `names` is empty. What did I do wrong? Since a lot of this is copied from Stata mailing list, I particularly don't understand the meaning of `local names : rownames villagemean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me what you want, but I think this might be it:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

webuse nhanes2f

svyset [pweight=finalwgt]
svy: mean zinc, over(sex)

matrix eb = e(b)

*----- what you want -----

levelsof sex, local(levsex)
local wc: word count `levsex'

gen avgsex = .
forvalues i = 1/`wc' {
    replace avgsex = eb[1,`i'] if sex == `:word `i' of `levsex''
}

list sex zinc avgsex in 1/10
```

I make use of two *extended macro functions*:

```
local wc: word count `levsex'
```

and

```
`:word `i' of `levsex''
```

The first one returns the number of words in a string; the second returns the nth token of a string. The `help` entry for extended macro functions is `help extended_fcn`. Better yet, read the manuals, starting with: [[U] 18.3 Macros](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u18.pdf). You will see there (18.3.8) that I use an abbreviated form.

### Some notes on your original post

Your loop doesn't do what you intend (although again, not crystal clear to me) because you are supplying a list (with one element: the text *name*). You can see it running and comparing:

```
local names 1 2 3

foreach v in names {
    display "`v'"
}

foreach v in `names' {
    display "`v'"
}

foreach v of local names {
    display "`v'"
}
```

You need to read the corresponding `help` files to set that right.

As for the question in your original post, `: rownames` is another extended macro function but for matrices. See `help matrix`, #11.

My impression is that for the kind of things you are trying to achieve, you need to dig deeper into the manuals. Furthermore, If you have not read the initial chapters of the **Stata User's Guide**, then you must do so.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I need. Could you elaborate on `if sex == `:word `i' of `levsex''`, especially the `:word` part? A pointer towards a help page would be appreciated. (Also how to know which help page to look in the first place? The general approach of `help :word`, `help word` does not help.

Comment: I've added/modified my answer. It should help.